# Is it possible to use null datapoints with a datetime x-axis?

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to use the type:'datetime' for my x-axis, and am getting a graph on a vertical line and dates going all the way back to 1970.  Is there any way to circumvent this error?

Here's my use case: I'm tracking my page performance at regular intervals.  if the server goes down for any reason or the metric was unable to be tracked, then we end up with a gap in the line.  the requirement is to show this as datetime, but if i populate the series with any null datapoints, Highcharts throws an error 15.

```
series: [{
    data: [
        {x:1389254400000,y:10},
        {x:1389554400000,y:9},
        null,
        {x:1389854400000,y:12}]
}]
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/agjZB/23/

If i remove the null datapoint, everything works fine.  Thanks for the extra eyes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You have to make the NULL point the same format as your other points.
- Or, don't include it. If you have no data for timestamp x why include it or if you have no data at all why include it?

Example of option 1:

```
series: [{
    data: [
        {x:1389254400000,y:10},
        {x:1389554400000,y:9},
        {x:1389554400000,y:null},
        {x:1389854400000,y:12}]
}]
```

Comment: ah, perfect!  Thanks!  I need to include it so that it calls to the viewer's attention that there were periods where metrics were unable to be captured, which can signify things such as power outages, server down, maintenance windows, etc. The data has timestamps, just no values within.

Answer (score 0):

For line chart you shouldn't use points with the same x value, becasue a few feateaures like tooltip will not work correct. You need to set scatter type and [lineWidth](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.lineWidth) as 2.

Comment: the data i was using actually had slightly different x-axis values.  the example in the accepted answer actually had just copied the 2nd object in the array to demo how to add null datapoints when you are using datetime as the x-axis type.